# Measuring page performance with Fiddler2 with Ie6 loaded from Spoon.net

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, internet-explorer-6, fiddler

As per title i am trying to measure page performance in IE6 that has been loaded with Spoon.net.

Am trying to use Fiddler2 but it does not seem to recognise the browser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddler shouldn't care what framework you're using; it listens to WinInet and acts as a proxy to it.  Local traffic doesn't go through WinInet, so you won't see it captured in Fiddler.  If you're using localhost for your server, try changing it to `http://ipv4.fiddler` and see if that allows your traffic to be captured.